# Can't get my text file to be read in Visual Studio C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, text, binary-tree

So I have a lab for my compsci class, and the professor and TA use Eclipse however, I could not get that to run for me properly so I tried Visual Studio instead. The problem I'm having is that I can't get my program to read in the text file I want, so that it can perform the operations it needs to.

This is the code I have below:

```
struct wordpair { string key; string following; };

int compare(wordpair a, wordpair b) {
if (a.key  < b.key) return -1;
if (a.key == b.key) return  0;
if (a.key  > b.key) return  1;
}

int main() {
ArrayDeque<string> A;
Treap1<wordpair> bst;
string k, l;

ifstream textstream("c:\\Users\\Jay\\Documents\\textfile.txt");
int t = clock();
textstream >> k;
A.add(0, k);
// insert wordpairs
while (textstream >> l) {
    wordpair w;
    w.key = k; w.following = l;
    bst.add(w);
    k = l;
    A.add(0, k);
}
// do some searches
for (int i = 0; i < 3*A.size(); ++i){
    wordpair w;
    w.key = A.get(rand()%A.size());
    bst.find(w);
}
cout << "time for " << bst.size() << " adds and " << 3*A.size() << " searches is " << clock()-t << endl;

char c;
cin >> c;
```

}

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. BTW I am using a PC, Windows &, Visual Studio Express 2010, coding in C++

Comment: Please be more specific about the error you are seeing.

Comment: 3 upvotes for a vague question?

Comment: It's either sock puppetry, or folks have started their drinking games early.